# Can you simplify summation of binomial products

Tags: math, binomial-coefficients

Is there a way to simplify the following term:

sum(binom(m, i)*binom(n, i)*factorial(i), i = 1..min(n,m))

where binom is the binominal coefficient.

Thanks!

Comment: is `m` positive? Is `m>=i`? What have you done so far?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming and is only about combinatorics which is math so belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One simple-minded approach is to tabulate that summation for different values of m and n, and then see if those values are known anywhere. Take a look at the OEIS (On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences). Good luck and have fun.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is stackoverflow and not math.stackexchange, it is only reasonable to assume that you plan to actually implement a program to compute this sum. With that in mind, I'll be doing a few "simplifications" that you normally wouldn't do in a purely mathematical / hypothetical setting.

First, know that

```
binom(n, i) => factorial(n) / (factorial(i) * factorial(n - i))
```

Plugging this into your equation, we can cancel out two `factorial(i)` terms.

```
factorial(n) * factorial(m) / ((factorial(i) * factorial(n - i) * factorial(m - i))
```

Now, if we make a function `product(a, b)` which takes the product of all numbers `[a, b]` inclusive, we can split apart these factorials into ranges which cancel out. To make the following snippet more concise, I abbreviate factorial as `fac` and product as `prod`.

```
fac(n)*fac(m) / (fac(i) * fac(n-i) * fac(m-i))
=> prod(m+1, n) * fac(m)**2 / (fac(i) * fac(n-i) * fac(m-i))
=> prod(m+1, n) * fac(m)**2 / (fac(i) * prod(m-i+1,n-i) * fac(m-i)**2)
=> prod(m+1, n) * prod(m-i+1,m)**2 / (fac(i) * prod(m-i+1,n-i))
=> prod(m+1, n) * prod(m-i+1,m) / (fac(i) * prod(m+1,n-i))
=> prod(n-i+1, n) * prod(m-i+1,m) / fac(i)
```

So at the end, we have

```
product(n-i+1, n) * product(m-i+1,m) / factorial(i)
```

-which requires significantly fewer multiplications. Now of course, the ideal way to compute this is not to evaluate the functions I have described above- the intermediate values will still be quite large.

The first option would be to start multiplying the values in each `product()`, and attempt to divide out smaller factors from `factorial()`. This may be time consuming however, since you will waste many more cycles checking for divisibility than actually reducing the number.

Another option would be to construct three sets, representing the numbers to be multiplied in each function call. Then take the intersection of one of the `product` sets with the `factorial` set, and subtract these elements from each of the original sets. Then repeat this process with the other `product` set and the new `factorial` set. Then multiply out the values in each set as before.

A smarter option yet would be to obtain the prime factorization of each number multiplied in `product()` and `factorial()` (maybe via lookup table), and then simply sum up the counts of each factor in `product()` and subtract away `factorial()`. Then you can just multiply by powers of each prime factor, which themselves can be computed faster via exponentiation by squaring (or even lookup tables, for smaller powers & factors).